# Sqlite ..read FILENAME command will not work

Tags: sqlite

When I use the .read FILENAME command in sqlite it will read commands from a .sql file no problem
but when that file contains further .read FILENAME commands sqlite will not read those files.
It seems like the .read FILENAME command can only be used in the command line.
So Am I meant to place all my table creation commands in the one file?
if so what sort of craziness is that?
PS I am using command line SQLite for purposes of getting my database schema sorted before using sqlite with a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [dot-commands like `.read` are part of the sqlite3 shell](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) and not a feature of SQL as recognized by sqlite. The `.read` command just executes the SQL in the file, it does not execute it as a sqlite3 command shell file.

> So Am I meant to place all my table creation commands in the one file?

That seems like a reasonable thing to do, especially since later at this point:

> PS I am using command line SQLite for purposes of getting my database schema sorted before using sqlite with a programming language.

... you won't have sqlite3 shell available at all and are restricted to SQL only.